# RxJS websocket how to resubscribe listening to the events when socket reconnects

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have created an angular service for [websocket using RxJS](https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/webSocket).
I have handled the ping/pong and also reconnecting using [retry](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/retry) operator

my Websocket Service looks like

```js
export class SocketService implements OnDestroy {
  private socket$: WebSocketSubject<any> | null = null;
  private pingInterval$!: Observable<number>;
  private destroyPing$ = new Subject<void>();
  private PING_INTERVAL = 8 * 60 * 1000;
  private readonly RETRY_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000;
  private needManualReconnectionSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  needManualReconnection$ = this.needManualReconnectionSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() {}
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroyPing$.next();
    this.destroyPing$.complete();
    if (this.socket$ && !this.socket$.closed) this.socket$.complete();
  }

  public connect(params: any): void {
    if (!this.socket$ || this.socket$?.closed) {
      const observable = this.getNewWebSocket(params.url);
      observable
      .pipe( retry({ delay: this.RETRY_INTERVAL }))
      .subscribe({
        next: (data) => console.log('[Websocket Service] Next:', data),
        error: (err) => console.error('[Websocket Service] Error:', err),
        complete: () => {
          //I'm using AWS websocket api gateway. it closes after 2hours and complete is called so I listen to this variable change and manually reconnect in my component
          this.needManualReconnectionSubject.next(true);
        }
      });
      this.socket$ = observable;
      this.setPingInterval();
    }
  }

  public reconnectOnServerSideClosure(params: any): void {
    this.disconnect();
    this.destroyPing$.next();
    this.destroyPing$.complete();
    this.needManualReconnectionSubject.next(false);
    this.connect(params);
  }

  public disconnect(): void {
    if (this.socket$ && !this.socket$.closed) {
      this.socket$.complete();
      this.socket$ = null;
    }
  }

  public getSocket(): WebSocketSubject<any> | null {
    return this.socket$;
  }

  private getNewWebSocket(url: string): WebSocketSubject<any> {
    const socket: WebSocketSubject<any> = webSocket({
      url,
      openObserver: {
        next: () => {}
      },
      closeObserver: {
        next: () => {}
      }
    });
    return socket;
  }

  ping() {
    if (!this.socket$) throw new Error('WebSocket connection is not initialized.');    
    const message: PingMessage = { action: 'ping' };
    this.socket$.next(message);
  }

  private setPingInterval(): void {
    this.pingInterval$ = interval(this.PING_INTERVAL);
    this.pingInterval$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyPing$)).subscribe(() => {
      this.ping();
    });
  }

  //for emitting events to the server
  emitEvent( event: string, data: any = {} ): void {
    if (!this.socket$) throw new Error('WebSocket connection is not initialized.');
    const message: WebSocketMessage = { action: event, data };
    this.socket$.next(message);
  }

  onEvent(event: string): Observable<any> {
    if (!this.socket$) throw new Error('WebSocket connection is not initialized.');    
    return this.socket$.pipe(
      filter((response: WebSocketResponse) => response.event === event),
      map((response: WebSocketResponse) => response.data),
    );
  }
}
```

In my component I connect and subscribe to some custom events of my own which I listen to react accordingly to the event

```js
this.socketService.connect(params);
this.socketSubscriptions = new Subscription();

this.socketSubscriptions.add(
   this.socketService.onEvent('editProfile').subscribe((data: any) => {
     //get notified when someone is editing profile do something as a reaction
   })
);

this.socketSubscriptions.add(
   this.socketService.onEvent('deleteProfile').subscribe((data: any) => {
     //do something...
   })
);
```

**My Problem**
When the device sleeps the websocket connection gets finished from browser side so when device resume work a new connection is created because of the `retry`. But unfortunately the events which  I have subscribed for are lost ( such as the `editProfile` here) so now when someone edits a profile I can see the messages coming in the network tab of the wss connection but I cannot react to those messages. I actually logged the `this.socket$` and noticed that the `currentObservers` array of `_output` field has gone down to 1 when a reconnect happens if that info is helpful.

Is there a way to re-subscribe to the subscribed events on reconnection. Perhaps if there is a way to know if a successful reconnect has occurred which I can use to re-subscribe to the events.